# How to mock a callback function for testing which is inside the arguments of another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

My requirement is to mock the callback function which is inside the arguments of another function for unit testing.

```
 var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
 var APICall = require('./requestFile');

 function Helper(){
 this.request = new APICall();
  }

 Helper.prototype.getData = function (done) {
    var headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
    };
    var _self = this;
    this.request.get(this.pub_URL, get_headers, function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log("Got data: ", body);
            done(null, body);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error occured while fetching data: " + err)
            done(err, null);
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

I want to mock the callback function which this.request.get() calls as an argument so that my testing can cover the else block 
        console.log("Error occured while fetching data: " + err).

Here is my test file with the code base

```js
const Helper = require('../Helper');
var APICall = require('../requestFile');

let hlp = new Helper();

describe('APP', function() {
  before(function() {
    let res = {
      statusCode: 500
    }
    let err = {
      message: 'errors present'
    };
    var get_headers = {
      'content-type': "application/json",
    };
    sinon.stub(APICall.prototype, 'get').callsFake(function(done) {
      done(err, res)
    })

  })

  after(function() {
    APIRequester.prototype.get.restore();
  });
  it('should tell errors when request gets called for', function(done) {

    hlp.getData(function(err, data) {
      expect(data).to.be.a('string')
      done()
    })
  })

})
```

Comment: This is not possible without 1) intercepting the `XMLHTTPRequest` call OR 2) brute force replacement of the `get` method. If it was a named function, that would be different.

Comment: @RandyCasburn suppose I intercept the XMLHTTPRequest call then how is it possible?? Or even I do brute force replacement of the get method then how this can be achieved

Comment: Many modern testing frameworks intercept XHRs. Your interceptor would simply replace the functionality of both the XHR get method that is being intercepted and, more importantly for you purposes, allow you to replace the callback with your mock.

Comment: Brute force: `RequestClassDefinition.get = myNewGet() function` - yeah, don't do this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am trying sinon.stub to mock the XHR get method but its not working. Please look into the post of what I did

Comment: _**but its not working**_ - that's too bad. Oh...wait, you want help with that! Define _its not working_ in detail or provide your entire code base.

Comment: Go here: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-xhr-and-server/

Comment: @RandyCasburn:I have provided my entire code base of the test file in the post.Please correct it as its not working.

Comment: Entire code base means entire - you cannot expect me to write test code without understanding the architecture of your solution. But, guessing away at it I created a Gist for your review. If it doesn't work there is not much I can do about it given my current knowledge of your application: https://gist.github.com/randycasburn/6b1bea345fcab5d4f38ec845b54b5f7d

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`helper.js`:

```js
const APICall = require("./request");

function Helper() {
  this.request = new APICall();
  this.pub_URL = "https://github.com";
}

Helper.prototype.getData = function(done) {
  const headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  };
  this.request.get(this.pub_URL, headers, function(err, res, body) {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log("Got data: ", body);
      done(null, body);
    } else {
      console.log("Error occured while fetching data: " + err);
      done(err, null);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = Helper;
```

`request.js`:

```js
function APICall() {}
APICall.prototype.get = function(url, headers, callback) {};

module.exports = APICall;
```

`helper.test.js`:

```js
const APICall = require("./request");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const Helper = require("./helper");

describe("56827977", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should get data correctly", () => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    const mRes = { statusCode: 200 };
    const mBody = "fake data";
    sinon.stub(APICall.prototype, "get").yields(null, mRes, mBody);
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    helper.getData(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(
      APICall.prototype.get,
      "https://github.com",
      {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      sinon.match.func,
    );
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, null, "fake data");
  });

  it("should handle error", () => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    const mError = new Error("network error");
    sinon.stub(APICall.prototype, "get").yields(mError, null, null);
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    helper.getData(callback);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(
      APICall.prototype.get,
      "https://github.com",
      {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      sinon.match.func,
    );
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(callback, mError, null);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  56827977
Got data:  fake data
    ✓ should get data correctly
Error occured while fetching data: Error: network error
    ✓ should handle error


  2 passing (10ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |    88.89 |      100 |                   |
 helper.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 helper.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 request.js     |      100 |      100 |       50 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56827977